# PySpark collect significantly speeds up the same query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I recently observe that if I run collect() on some transformation in Spark as warm up, the later execution runs much faster. Instead, if I just run show(), it does not have impact on query performance. I cannot find any related posts about this. Any reason why this is happening?

I attach a code snippet below to reproduce the behavior. Basically, the `run_collect_to_warm_up` reports lower time than the other function.

```py
from time import perf_counter

import pandas as pd

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("TEST").getOrCreate()

sdf = spark.range(0, 1000000).withColumn(
  'id', col('id')
).withColumn('v', rand())

@pandas_udf(DoubleType())
def pandas_plus_one(pdf):
    return pdf + 1


def run_collect_to_warm_up():
    res = sdf.select(pandas_plus_one(col("v")))
    res.collect()

    st = perf_counter()
    for _ in range(10):
        res.show()
    print(f"Time (warming up with collect): {(perf_counter() - st) * 1000}")


def run_show_to_warm_up():
    res = sdf.select(pandas_plus_one(col("v")))
    res.show()

    st = perf_counter()
    for _ in range(10):
        res.show()
    print(f"Time (warming up with show): {(perf_counter() - st) * 1000}")


run_show_to_warm_up()
run_collect_to_warm_up()
```